# What are the mask values for decoding websocket frames?

Tags: java, html, websocket

I know that ENCODED are the bytes array, but what is MASK, what are his values?

```
 var DECODED = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < ENCODED.length; i++) {
        DECODED[i] = ENCODED[i] ^ MASK[i % 4];
    }
```

I've found this example on the web, the question is how can I know what are the MASK values?

any hint or links please? but in the google examples I find only this type of code, but I wish to see explicitly the MASK values, any help please

```
    pstream = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(csocket.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    char[] buff = new char[4];

    pstream.read(buf);

//now buf have that masks?
```

Comment: Where did you get that code from? What code did encode the data? Why are you using strings for byte arrays at all?

Comment: @Bergi https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets/Writing_WebSocket_servers#Reading_and_Unmasking_the_Data - can you check it, there are this code, but I can't understand what are the MASK values, any ideas? cause I'am not that smart to understand from where they getted that MASK array, I can't learn further because I'am stuck in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right above that code snippet it says:

> If the MASK bit was set (and it should be, for client-to-server messages), **read the next 4 octets (32 bits); this is the masking key**.

You can find the MASK bit in the [data frame format description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets/Writing_WebSocket_servers#Format).

So the pseudocode could be extended to

```
var LEN = decodeLength(buffer);
var MASK = buffer.read(4);
var ENCODED = buffer.read(LEN);
var DECODED = new Buffer(LEN);
for (var i = 0; i < ENCODED.length; i++) {
    DECODED[i] = ENCODED[i] ^ MASK[i % 4];
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for this explanation, lets me ask just one more question(cause its a bit complicated for me), so as I understand if I have a BufferedReader reader at java, I can read that mask data by using reader.read(buf) with buffer with size 4?

Comment: code updated, please can you check if I'am reading it right in java?

Comment: Yes, the mask (if present) is 32 bits that need to be XORed into the data for decoding. I don't know what to use in Java for that however. You really should have tagged the question with Java instead of JavaScript!